# How to sum fibonacci numbers based on a condition?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to sum fibonacci numbers based on a condition. Let's say I have my function:

```
def findingSum(lower: Int, upper: Int): Int{}
```

which passes 2 numbers. If I pass `findingSum(20 , 90)`, my function should find the sum of the Fibonacci numbers between those numbers, in other words I should get the sum of  21+ 34 + 55 + 89.

Code:

```
def  findingSum(lower: Int, upper: Int): Int = {
    var sum=0;
    var current 
    var prev = 1
    var prevprev = 0

    for(i <- (n.length-1))          
    {
        current = prev + prevprev;        
        sum += current;
        prevprev = prev;                 
        prev = current;                   
    }               
    println("Result= " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you create a Fibonacci stream.

```
def fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1)(_+_)
```

Then you take, drop, and sum. (Or drop, take, and sum.  It works either way.)

```
fib.takeWhile(_ <= upper).dropWhile(_ <= lower).sum
```

One advantage to holding Fibonacci numbers in a `Stream` like this is that the calculations are cached.  Once the 10th Fibonacci number (55) has been calculated it never needs to be recalculated, it's a simple lookup to get `fib(10)` thereafter.

So, to put it in context:

```
def findingSum(lower: Int, upper: Int): Int = {
  def fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1)(_+_)
  fib.takeWhile(_ <= upper).dropWhile(_ <= lower).sum
}
```

But this arrangement does eliminate the nice caching I mentioned earlier, so it might make sense to define `fib` somewhere outside of your function so that it is not redefined on every call. I'd probably go with something like:

```
def fib: Stream[Int] = 0 #:: fib.scan(1)(_+_)
def findingSum(l: Int, u: Int) = fib.takeWhile(_ <= u).dropWhile(_ <= l).sum
```

**CORRECTION**

The info on Stream caching comes from [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/stream-view-iterator.html), which states:

> ... a Stream is a List whose tail is a lazy val. Once computed, a value
>   stays computed and is reused.

However, later on that same page it also says this about Streams:

> ... main benefit is writing infinite sequences (particularly sequences
>   recursively defined). One can avoid keeping all of the Stream in
>   memory, though, by making sure you don’t keep a reference to its head
>   (for example, by using def instead of val to define the Stream).

So while I was not wrong about `Stream` caching, my code examples failed to actually take advantage of it.

Replace `def fib: Stream...//etc.` with `lazy val fib: Stream...//etc.` and I think we're good.

Comment: I'm still learning Scala. How would you implement your code with my function? def  findingSum(lower: Int, upper: Int): Int = {  ....btw thanks for your help :)!!

Comment: Are you sure `fib` will be cached if you  call `findingSum` multiple times? It is a `def`. If so, please give some explanation because that is interesting.

Comment: @Łukasz, you are correct.  I've added a clarification/correction.  Thanks for checking up on me.

Comment: I think that with the Stream it might happen that the sum of 1.000.000 Fibonacci numbers will require evaluation of every stream item and keeping it in memory. Kinda something that is not desirable for just getting the sum. But looks cool anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
def findingSum(lower: Int, upper: Int): Int = {
  (lower to upper).filter(isFibonacci).sum
}
```

there you go, (I assume you have that method to verify if the number is a Fibonacci number in scope)

Comment: your solution works but for some reason it sums the numbers minus 1. Lets  say to sum the fibonnaci numbers from 0 to 10 is 20 , but your solution throws 19

Comment: I replaced "until", that excludes the upper limit - to "to", that includes one. Should work as you expect now. Do you take some course in Scala? Is this an assignment?

Comment: Im learning scala on my own. Nope its not an assignment. Also even though you changed it from until  to "to" still doesnt work...

Comment: somehow the sum is minus 1 and not sure why

Comment: I'm voting you up. Thanks for you help!

Comment: 1+2+3+5+8=19, not 20. I assume the 20 came from summing 1 twice, since it appears twice in the fibonacci sequence: 1,1,2,3,5,8.